# Are the following sets open?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> **Question:** Are the following sets open? Provide reasons for your answers.
>
> 1. $A = \{(x,y): x^2 + y^2 \le1  \}$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$
> 2. $A = \{(x,y): 0 \leq y <1 \}$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$
> 3. $A = \{ (x,y,z) : z>0\}$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$
> 4. $A = \{(x,y,z) : x=y=z \}$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$
> 5. $A = \{(x,y): x \geq 0 \}$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$
> 6. $A = \{ (x,y): x>0 \}$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$
> 7. $[1,2]$ in $\mathbb{R}$

**My Attempts:**

1. $A^0 = \{(x,y): x^2 + y^2 < 1 \} \neq A \implies A$ not open
2. $A^0 = \{ (x,y): 0 < y < 1 \} \neq A \implies A$ not open
3. $A^0 = \{ (x,y,z) : z>0 \} = A \implies A$ is open
4. (I am not sure about this one at all)
5. $A^0 = \{(x,y): x >0\} \neq A \implies A$ not open
6. $A^0 = \{ (x,y): x>0 \} = A \implies A$ is open
7. $([1,2])^0 = (1,2) \neq [1,2] \implies [1,2]$ not open

Are these correct?  Also, any hints about the ones I am unsure about will be much appreciated :).

I am reading through some notes on open sets and came across these examples, which I attempted to test how well my understanding of open sets is.

Comment: For #4, the set is a line. Think of what it would mean for a point to be in the interior of the line, and you will see that the line has no interior. This means that $A^0=\emptyset\neq A$.

Comment: @ColinDefant - Thank you! :). That makes perfect sense! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these are correct. As for 4., keep in mind that $A$ is a line in 3-space.  It shouldn't be to hard to see that $A^o=\emptyset$.